# How shall I understand the conditions for merging by diff3 to be well-defined?

Tags: diff, diff3

In [diffutils' manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff3-Merging.html)

> ```
> diff3 mine older yours
> ```
>
> You can remember the order of the arguments by noting that they are in
> alphabetical order.
>
> You can think of this as subtracting older from yours and adding the
> result to mine, or as merging into mine the changes that would turn
> older into yours. This merging is well-defined as long as **mine and
> older match in the neighborhood of each such change**. This fails to
> be true **when all three input files differ** or **when only older
> differs**; we call this a conflict. When all three input files diff
> er, we call the conflict an overlap.
>
> ...
>
> The ‘-e’, ‘-3’ and ‘-x’ options select only **unmerged changes, i.e. changes where mine and yours differ**; they ignore **changes from older to yours where mine and yours are identical**, because they assume that such changes have already been merged.

What does "mine and older match in the neighborhood of each such change" mean?

Does "when only older differs" mean that mine and yours are the same but different from older? Isn't merging straightforward in that we can just use either mine or yours? Why isn't merging well-defined in this case?

How do the three cases cover all the possible cases:

- When "mine and older match in the neighborhood of each such change"
- "when all three input files differ"
- "when only older differs"?

Is "changes from older to yours where mine and yours are identical" the same as the changes "when only older differs"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does "mine and older match in the neighborhood of each such change" mean?

“mine and older match in the neighborhood of each such change” means that when considering each change between “older” and “yours”, the context of the change can be found in “mine” too. Put another way, it means that “mine” and “older” are identical as far as each individual change between “older” and “yours” is concerned. Consider

```
mine            other           yours
------------------------------------------------
Some text       Some text       Some text
Some more text  Some more test  Changed text
Continues       Continues       Continues
Mine changes    This is gone    This is gone
The file ends   The file ends   The file ends
```

One line has changed between “other” and “mine”, and another has changed between “other” and “yours”. When looking at the change from “other” to “yours”, we find the same context in “mine”, so the change can be applied to “mine” with no ambiguity or conflict.

> Does "when only older differs" mean that mine and yours are the same but different from older?

Yes.

> Isn't merging straightforward in that we can just use either mine or yours? Why isn't merging well-defined in this case?

The definition of “well-defined” is that the context of the change from “older” to “yours” is identical in “mine”. When “mine” and “yours” are identical, and differ from “older”, then by definition the change isn’t well-defined.

This might seem surprising, but the guiding principle of three-way merges is that any conflict, even if it results in identical content, must be identified and examined by the user. I don’t have an example to hand but it does happen that a given line is identical in “mine” and “yours”, but given other changes which are being merged, isn’t desirable as-is in the merge result.

Another way of considering this, is that the aim of a three-way merge is to reconcile two diverging histories: the history which led from “older” to “mine”, and the history which led from “older” to “yours”. Even if both histories lead to the same content, they need to be re-evaluated and not blindly applied.

The developers of `diff3` did realise that such changes should often be applied anyway; the `-e`, `-3`, and `-x` options do this.

> How do the three cases cover all the possible cases?

The first case describes a global analysis, but I think the other two should be understood in the context of a single change. If we consider all three cases viewed per change (from “older” to “yours”), they become (remember “older” and “yours” are different):

- “mine” and “older” are identical
- “mine“ and “older” are different, and “mine” and “yours” are different
- “mine“ and “older” are different, and “mine” and “yours” are identical

Consider the truth table:

```
mine == older    mine == yours    older == yours    Case
--------------------------------------------------------
     Yes              Yes               Yes         N/A
     Yes              Yes               No          Imp.
     Yes              No                Yes         N/A
     Yes              No                No          1
     No               Yes               Yes         N/A
     No               Yes               No          3
     No               No                Yes         N/A
     No               No                No          2
```

N/A means the case isn’t considered: there is no change from “older” to “yours”. Imp. means the case is impossible (through transitivity of equality). This shows that three cases are sufficient to cover all possibilities.

> Is "changes from older to yours where mine and yours are identical" the same as the changes "when only older differs"?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks. Is "unmerged changes, i.e. changes where mine and yours differ" the same as either when "mine and older match in the neighborhood of each such change" or "when all three input files differ"?

Comment: It’s the same as both; see the truth table (lines 4 and 8).

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the meaning of whether merging is "well-defined": (1) "This merging is well-defined as long as mine and older match in the neighborhood of each such change." In that case, is merging done by choosing yours over mine and older? What does "well-defined" mean? (2)  "when only older differs",   mine and yours are the same but different from older, so isn't merging straightforward in that we can just choose either mine or yours over older? Why isn't merging well-defined in this case?

Comment: (3) In my guess,  merging isn't well defined if and only if mine, older and yous differ from one another, and is well defined if and only if any two of mine, older and yours are the same.

Comment: Thanks for update. (1) "The developers of diff3 did realise that such changes should often be applied anyway; the -e, -3, and -x options do this." Do you mean diff3 with the -e, -3, and -x options will automatically merge changes where yours and old differ and mine and yours are the same? How does it perform merging in such a case?

Comment: (2) "The ‘-e’, ‘-3’ and ‘-x’ options select only unmerged changes, i.e. changes where mine and yours differ".  So it select changes where merging is well defined (i.e. where mine and yours differ and mine and old are the same).  It "ignore changes from older to yours where mine and yours are identical, because they assume that such changes have already been merged. "  Does it believe that changes from older to yours where mine and yours are identical  are more straightforward to merge than changes where merging is well-defined (i.e. where mine and yours differ and mine and older are the same)?

Comment: (1) The `-e`, `-3`, and `-x` options all produce `ed` scripts to transform “mine” into the merge result. When a change is identical in “mine” and “yours”, those options cause it not to appear in the script. (2) Those options also select changes where all three files differ. `diff3` doesn’t believe anything, it implements its specification. The most straightforward changes to apply are the well-defined changes: applying them means applying the patch from “older” to “yours”, to “mine”. Other changes involve some level of decision; specifying `-e`, `-3`, or `-x` is a decision.

Comment: It seems Wikipedia also thinks in the same way as I do: "The three-way merge looks for sections which are the same in only two of the three files. In this case, there are two versions of the section, and the version which is in the common ancestor "C" is discarded, while the version that differs is preserved in the output. If "A" and "B" agree, that is what appears in the output. A section that is the same in "A" and "C" outputs the changed version in "B", and likewise a section that is the same in "B" and "C" outputs the version in "A"."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)

Comment: I’m explaining what `diff3` does, not commenting Wikipedia. Try it: `seq 1 21 > older; sed 's/^4$/changed/;s/^11$/changed/' older > mine; sed 's/^11$/changed/;s/^18$/changed/' older > yours; diff3 mine older yours`

Comment: `diff3 -m mine older yours` will show more clearly that `diff3` considers that a change where “mine” and “yours” are identical, and differ from “older”, is a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It is well defined in each of `mine` and `yours` is a change from `older`, such that they remove text; add text in a different place; or they change text, but don't both change the same text.

That is the computer can not know what is wanted if we both change the same thing (in different ways), or if we add something in the same place, then it does not know in what order to place them.